# FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 7)

Tags: flutter, dart, formatexception

I'm getting this error. How to resolve this.

```
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 7)
      public static final int right_side = 0x7f050036;
```

---

flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in shayari_card...
`Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8', path = '.\pubspec.lock'`

---- Log transcript ----

```
FINE: Pub 2.8.4

IO  : Spawning "cmd /c ver" in C:\Users\Mahender\Desktop\FlutterApps\shayari_card\.

IO  : Finished ver. Exit code 0.

    | stdout:

    | | 

    | | Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

    | Nothing output on stderr.

MSG : Resolving dependencies...

ERR : Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8', path = '.\pubspec.lock'

FINE: Exception type: FileSystemException

FINE: dart:io                                     _File.readAsStringSync

    | package:pub/src/io.dart 152:48              readTextFile

    | package:pub/src/lock_file.dart 82:38        new LockFile.load

    | package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 96:28       Entrypoint.lockFile

    | package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 222:19      Entrypoint.acquireDependencies.<fn>

    | package:pub/src/log.dart 394:18             progress

    | package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 216:24      Entrypoint.acquireDependencies

    | package:pub/src/command/get.dart 46:23      GetCommand.run

    | package:args/command_runner.dart 197:27     CommandRunner.runCommand

    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 191:39  PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>

    | dart:async                                  new Future.sync

    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 113:12           captureErrors.wrappedCallback

    | package:stack_trace                         Chain.capture

    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 126:11           captureErrors

    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 191:13  PubCommandRunner.runCommand

    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================

    | dart:async                                  Future.catchError

    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 113:52           captureErrors.wrappedCallback

    | package:stack_trace                         Chain.capture

    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 126:11           captureErrors

    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 191:13  PubCommandRunner.runCommand

    | dart:async                                  _completeOnAsyncReturn

    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart         PubCommandRunner._validatePlatform

    | dart:async                                  _completeOnAsyncReturn

    | package:pub/src/io.dart                     runProcess.<fn>

---- End log transcript ----
pub get failed (66; ---- End log transcript ----)
exit code 66
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: check it above {updated}. I think it is not a coding error by me

Comment: can delete you `pubspec.lock` file and run flutter pub get again?

Comment: Solved:- Pubspec file is updated now.